# How to remove duplicate words containing in ArrayList<String> in java

Tags: java

**I have used the below code:**

The output should be each word within the string in the ArrayList occurring only once.

**O/P:**

"This is a list and Arraylist with set". Any suggestion will be appreciated.

```
public class ArrayListTest {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    String s1="This is a list";
    String s2="This is a list and Arraylist";
    String s3="and Arraylist with set";

    ArrayList<String> al = new ArrayList<String>();
    al.add(s1);
    al.add(s2);
    al.add(s3);


        System.out.println(al);
        LinkedHashSet<String> lhs = new LinkedHashSet<String>();
        lhs.addAll(al);
        System.out.println(lhs);



    }

}
```

Comment: *The output should be each words containing once* - Then you should add each word individually (and not the whole String(s))

Comment: Flagging this as duplicate is pretty funny, though :)

Comment: Use .containts() method.

Comment: I have edited the question as i believe its not a duplicate question. Thanks for your suggestion.

Comment: Can someone please remove the duplicate tag as this is not a duplicate question.